# Prepend a column of data to a given list

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a list named DATA containing ten {x, y} elements. I need to prepend a column of data with 10 rows ranging from 0.1 to 1 with stepsize 0.1.

```
DATA = {{3, 4}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {1, 8}, {9, 5}, {7, 6}, {25, 15}, {1, 
   2}, {55, 0}, {10, 1}}
Table[Nest[Prepend[#, i] &, DATA[[j]], 1], {i, 0.1, 1, 0.1}, {j, 1, 10}]
```

However, the result is something bizarre. It is coming out to be a three-dimensional matrix.

[image]

How do I do it? It is due to some minor problem I guess, but I am unable to point it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
data= {{3, 4}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {1, 8}, {9, 5}, {7, 6}, {25, 15}, {1, 
   2}, {55, 0}, {10, 1}}

Transpose@Join[{Range[0.1, 1, 0.1]}, Transpose[data]]
```

OR

```
MapThread[Join, {List /@ Range[0.1, 1, 0.1], data}]
```

---

result:

> ```
> {{0.1, 3, 4}, {0.2, 5, 1}, {0.3, 5, 2}, {0.4, 1, 8}, {0.5, 9, 
>   5}, {0.6, 7, 6}, {0.7, 25, 15}, {0.8, 1, 2}, {0.9, 55, 0}, {1., 10, 
>   1}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much. You just helped me save weeks for calculation.

Comment: I am glad I was able to save you weeks. Thanks for the accept.

Comment: or `MapThread[Join[{#1},#2]&, {Range[0.1, 1, 0.1], data}]` , nearly the same.

Answer (score 7):

I noticed that you want 0.1 ~ 1 to be **prepended**. (**index**/10)

So this also works.

```
MapIndexed[Prepend[#1,First[#2]/10.]&,data]
```

> {{0.1, 3, 4}, {0.2, 5, 1}, {0.3, 5, 2}, {0.4, 1, 8}, {0.5, 9,
> 5}, {0.6, 7, 6}, {0.7, 25, 15}, {0.8, 1, 2}, {0.9, 55, 0}, {1., 10,
> 1}}

Answer (score 6):

Using the level argument of `Join`

```
Join[List /@ Range[0.1, 1, 0.1], data, 2]
```

gives the expected result:

```
{{0.1, 3, 4}, {0.2, 5, 1}, {0.3, 5, 2}, {0.4, 1, 8}, {0.5, 9, 5}, 
 {0.6, 7, 6}, {0.7, 25, 15}, {0.8, 1, 2}, {0.9, 55, 0}, {1., 10, 1}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `Do` and `PrependTo`:

```
data = {{3, 4}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {1, 8}, {9, 5},
        {7, 6}, {25, 15}, {1, 2}, {55, 0}, {10, 1}};

Module[{l = data}, Do[PrependTo[l[[i]], #[[i]]], {i, Length@#}] &@Range[0.1, 1, 0.1]; l]

(*{{0.1, 3, 4}, {0.2, 5, 1}, {0.3, 5, 2}, {0.4, 1, 8}, {0.5, 9, 5}, 
   {0.6, 7, 6}, {0.7, 25, 15}, {0.8, 1, 2}, {0.9, 55, 0}, {1., 10, 1}}*)
```

Or using `Cases`:

```
Cases[Thread@{List /@ Range[0.1, 1, 0.1], data}, {a_, b_} :> Catenate@{a, b}]

(*{{0.1, 3, 4}, {0.2, 5, 1}, {0.3, 5, 2}, {0.4, 1, 8}, {0.5, 9, 5}, 
   {0.6, 7, 6}, {0.7, 25, 15}, {0.8, 1, 2}, {0.9, 55, 0}, {1., 10, 1}}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data= {{3, 4}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {1, 8}, {9, 5}, {7, 6}, {25, 15}, 
       {1, 2}, {55, 0}, {10, 1}};
```

```
MapThread[Prepend,{data, Range[0.1, 1, 0.1]}]

    (*{
       {0.1,3,4},
       {0.2,5,1},
       {0.3,5,2},
       {0.4,1,8},
       {0.5,9,5},
       {0.6,7,6},
       {0.7,25,15},
       {0.8,1,2},
       {0.9,55,0},
       {1.,10,1}
      }
```

In more general terms:

```
mat = Array[a, {3, 4}];
vect= {10,20,30};
```

(1) Insert `vect` into `mat` as column 2:

```
MapThread[Insert[##,2]&, {mat, vect}]


(* {
    {a[1,1],10,a[1,2],a[1,3],a[1,4]},
    {a[2,1],20,a[2,2],a[2,3],a[2,4]},
    {a[3,1],30,a[3,2],a[3,3],a[3,4]}
   } *)
```

`vect` may be a column from `mat`:

```
MapThread[Insert[#,#[[3]],1]&,{mat}]

(*{
   {a[1,3],a[1,1],a[1,2],a[1,3],a[1,4]}, 
   {a[2,3],a[2,1],a[2,2],a[2,3],a[2,4]}, 
   {a[3,3],a[3,1],a[3,2],a[3,3],a[3,4]}
  }*)
```

(2) Append  `vect` to  `mat` as a column:

```
MapThread[Append, {mat, vect}]

(*{
    {a[1,1],a[1,2],a[1,3],a[1,4],10},
    {a[2,1],a[2,2],a[2,3],a[2,4],20},
    {a[3,1],a[3,2],a[3,3],a[3,4],30}
  }*)
```

(3) Prepend  `vect` to  `mat` as a column:

```
MapThread[Prepend, {mat, vect}]

(*{
    {10,a[1,1],a[1,2],a[1,3],a[1,4]},
    {20,a[2,1],a[2,2],a[2,3],a[2,4]},
    {30,a[3,1],a[3,2],a[3,3],a[3,4]}
  }*)
```